# font is not displaying using @font-face

Tags: css

I am trying to add font and its not working.

My fonts folder:

```
assets/fonts/
```

My Stylesheet folder

```
assets/css/
```

My CSS code

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"GE SS Two Medium";
    src:url("../fonts/GE_SS_Two_Medium.eot?") format("eot"),
    url("../fonts/GE_SS_Two_Medium.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/GE_SS_Two_Medium.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/GE_SS_Two_Medium.svg#GESSTwoMedium-Medium") format("svg");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}

body {
    font-family: "GE SS Two Medium";
    color: #0F4242;
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

Comment: Please check the path of the font correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `url("../fonts)`
You will go back to the root of your ftp server and than look for a folder fonts. Since the folder fonts is in assets the server can't find it.

I don't know the exact file structure of your ftp server. But you need to make sure the path is correct.

Example:

```
-- root
 -- assets
  -- fonts
  -- css
  -- js
```

your path will be:

```
url("../assets/fonts/GE_SS_Two_Medium.ttf") format("truetype")
```

Comment: now its working but only few letters are showing in the new font

Comment: What do you mean with only a few letters? Make sure you have the whole font package.